# What custom fields can I include in the SFMC send log?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, send-email, logging

I've just set up a SFMC send log and have included a few custom fields. But at first glance the data in the send log isn't that useful to me. How can I create a send log that includes data from the core SFMC data tables. Such as: 
 - emailname_
 - emailaddr
 - _subscriberkey
 - view_email_url
 - and send date-time, if possible.
I.e. a send log that contains send info that's useful to a marketer!
Any suggestions are welcome. The best one I've come across is here: [Feed a Send Log / Send History Data Extension automatically](http://webep.fr/feed-a-send-log-send-history-data-extension-automatically)
Surely the system send log can do this, though?

Comment: Hi you can create custom fields in the data extension. If they match a System name for example CampaignName MessageName etc will automatically populate. If you need different names you will need to use some AmpScript to set the variable names..

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewC! I appreciate your answer. I'm more than happy to use default System names. I would prefer it, actually. Where can I find a list of System names for default data points in the SFMC documentation? I've been pulling my hair out trying to find useful info for setting up a send log. I've tried using some personalisation strings from the System Data Tables: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/ ... although I'm starting to come around to the idea of setting AMPscript variables in every email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add additional fields using the name Marketing Cloud uses for these values, so they are populated automatically. For the send date you can add a Date column and set a default value of `GETDATE()` for example. AMPscript variables can also be logged to a column that is named like variable is, so `@YourVar` would be logged to the column `YourVar`. Make sure you set these additional columns to be nullable, so there is no error if the value isn't available.

**Here are some example column definitions:**

- EmailAddress (*Type:* EmailAddress, *Nullable:* True)
- SubscriberKey (*Type:* Set type to fit your key, *Nullable:* True)
- SendDate (*Type:* Date, *Nullable:* True, *Default Value:* `GETDATE()`)
- YourVar (*Type:* According to the data you have in your AMPscript-Variable, *Nullable:* True)

Comment: As AndrewC pointed out, you can also log the value of AMPScript personalisation strings and variables to the Send Log. The value of @myVar would be logged if the send log DE contains a field called "myVar".

Comment: Thank you for that piece of information, I added it to the answer!

Comment: Thanks Markus and @AndrewMcLeod, much appreciated. As mentioned above, I've tried using personalisation strings from the System Data tables in my send log, with varying degrees of success. I already have EmailAddress there and it's not being populated for triggered sends, it seems. I love the `GETDATE()`, thanks! I wouldn't have thought of that! Embarrassingly. More and more, I'm thinking that I might use AMPscript variables in every email, for flexibility. For example, I could set the send time to my local time then, which is Sydney, Australia.

Comment: Where can I find a list in the SFMC documentation of the default field names SFMC uses for these common data points? I can't find them ...

Comment: Are you referring to Personalization Strings - https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings? Bare in mind that some of these strings start with underscores and you'll not be able to create fields in your Send Log whose name starts in this way. You may want to consider AMPScript variables for these. A good idea might be to place this type of AMPScript in the Account Header defined in the Admin Section of the Email Application.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm referring to. And I did notice that strings starting with an underscore didn't get added to the send log. Good idea about the auto Account Header. I might also use `%%=ContentArea("your-id")=%%` in a content area to draw in a content block containing the AMPscript at send time. I assume that would be a safe way to do it?